# Can I use alivepdf read a exist pdf from external?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, air, alivepdf

As title, any detail documentation about alivepdf are very thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlivePDF contains templates support which allows you to import an existing PDF document and use it as a template, which is very interesting and a much request feature. This only works with Adobe AIR aplications.

Comment: I'm using air. Could you tell me which class of alivepdf could do this for me? thanks!

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://gonzalo.huerta.cl/?p=3 Please mark my anwer useful